# Why to put a property variable in the constructor

Tags: python, oop, constructor, properties

From other languages I am used to code a `class property` and afterwards I can access this without having it in the `constructor` like

```
Class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._value = 0
    @property
    my_property(self):
        print('I got the value:' & self._value)
```

In almost every example I worked through the property variable was in the constructor `self._value` like this

```
Class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, value = 0):
        self._value = value
```

To me this makes no sence since you want to set it in the property. Could anyone explain to me what is the use of placing the `value variable` in the `constructor`?

Comment: Btw `print('I got the value:' & self._value)` should be `print('I got the value: %d' % self._value)` I guess.

Comment: What do you mean "set it in the property"? That property is not settable.

Comment: It's easy to understand, we use `@property` to get dynamical value. The simplest example could be getting a value based on the current time. It is not a static value so you cannot just assign it during the initialization time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `@property` is not a decorator for a variable, it is a [decorator for function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=property#property) that allows it to behave like a property. You still need to create a class variable to use a function decorated by `@property`:

> The `@property` decorator turns the `voltage()` method into a “getter” for a read-only attribute with the same name, and it sets the docstring for voltage to “Get the current voltage.”
>
> A property object has getter, setter, and deleter methods usable as decorators that create a copy of the property with the corresponding accessor function set to the decorated function. This is best explained with an example:

Answer (score 7):

Python objects are not struct-based (like C++ or Java), they are dict-based (like Javascript). This means that the instances attributes are dynamic (you can add new attributes or delete existing ones at runtime), and are not defined at the class level but at the instance level, and they are defined quite simply by assigning to them. While they can technically be defined anywhere in the code (even outside the class), the convention (and good practice) is to define them (eventually to default values) in the initializer (the `__init__` method - the real constructor is named `__new__` but there are very few reasons to override it) to make clear which attributes an instance of a given class is supposed to have.

Note the use of the term "attribute" here - in python, we don't talk about "member variables" or "member functions" but about "attributes" and "methods". Actually, since Python classes are objects too (instance of the `type` class or a subclass of), they have attributes too, so we have instance attributes (which are per-instance) and class attributes (which belong to the class object itself, and are shared amongst instances). A class attribute can be looked up on an instance, as long as it's not shadowed by an instance attribute of the same name.

Also, since Python functions are objects too (hint: in Python, everything - everything you can put on the RHS of an assignment that is - is an object), there are no distinct namespaces for "data" attributes and "function" attributes, and Python's "methods" are actually functions defined on the class itself - IOW they are class attributes that happen to be instances of the `function` type. Since methods need to access the instance to be able to work on it, [there's a special mechanism that allow to "customize" attribute access](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) so a given object - if it implements the proper interface - can return something else than itself when it's looked up on an instance but resolved on the class. This mechanism is used by functions so they turn themselves into methods (callable objects that wraps the function and instance together so you don't have to pass the instance to the function), but also more generally as the support for computed attributes.

The `property` class is a generic implementation of computed attributes that wraps a getter function (and eventually a setter and a deleter) - so in Python "property" has a very specific meaning (the `property` class itself or an instance of it). Also, the `@decorator` syntax is nothing magical (and isn't specific to properties), it's just syntactic sugar so given a "decorator" function:

```
 def decorator(func):
     return something
```

this:

```
 @decorator
 def foo():
     # code here
```

is just a shortcut for:

```
 def foo():
     # code here

 foo = decorator(foo)
```

Here I defined `decorator` as a function, but just any callable object (a "callable" object is an instance of a class that defines the `__call__` magic method) can be used instead - and Python classes are callables (that's even actually by calling a class that you instanciate it).

So back to your code:

```
# in py2, you want to inherit from `object` for
# descriptors and other fancy things to work.
# this is useless in py3 but doesn't break anything either...

class MyClass(object):

    # the  `__init__` function will become an attribute
    # of the `MyClass` class object

    def __init__(self, value=0):
        # defines the instance attribute named `_value`
        # the leading underscore denotes an "implementation attribute"
        # - something that is not part of the class public interface
        # and should not be accessed externally (IOW a protected attribute)
        self._value = value

    # this first defines the `my_property` function, then
    # pass it to `property()`, and rebinds the `my_property` name
    # to the newly created `property` instance. The `my_property` function
    # will then become the property's getter (it's `fget` instance attribute)
    # and will be called when the `my_property` name is resolved on a `MyClass` instance

    @property
    my_property(self):
        print('I got the value: {}'.format(self._value))
        # let's at least return something
        return self._value
```

You may then want to inspect both the class and an instance of it:

```
>>> print(MyClass.__dict__)
{'__module__': 'oop', '__init__': <function MyClass.__init__ at 0x7f477fc4a158>, 'my_property': <property object at 0x7f477fc639a8>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'MyClass' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'MyClass' objects>, '__doc__': None}
>>> print(MyClass.my_property)
<property object at 0x7f477fc639a8>
>>> print(MyClass.my_property.fget)
<function MyClass.my_property at 0x7f477fc4a1e0>
>>> m = MyClass(42)
>>> print(m.__dict__)
{'_value': 42}
>>> print(m.my_property)
I got the value: 42
42
>>>
```

As a conclusion: if you hope to do anything usefull with a language, you have to learn *this* language - you cannot just expect it to work as other languages you know. While some features are based on common concepts (ie functions, classes etc), they can actually be implemented in a totally different way (Python's object model has almost nothing in common with Java's one), so just trying to write Java (or C or C++ etc) in Python will not work (just like trying to write Python in Java FWIW).

NB: just for the sake of completeness: Python objects *can* actually be made "struct-based" by using `__slots__` - but the aim here is not to prevent dynamically adding attributes (that's only a side effect) but to make instances of those classes "lighter" in size (which is useful when you know you're going to have thousands or more instances of them at a given time).

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you're coming from a language like C++ or Java where it is common to make attributes private and then write explicit getters and setters for them? In Python there is no such thing as private other than by convention and there is no need to write getters and setters for a variable that you only need to write and read as is. @property and the corresponding setter decorators can be used if you want to add additional behaviour (e.g. logging acccess) or you want to have pseudo-properties that you can access just like real ones, e.g. you might have a `Circle` class that is defined by it's radius but you could define a `@property` for the diameter so you can still write circle.diameter.

More specifically to your question: You want to have the property as an argument of the initializer if you want to set the property at the time when you create the object. You wouldn't want to create an empty object and then immediately fill it with properties as that would create a lot of noise and make the code less readable.

Just an aside: `__init__` isn't actually a constructor. The constructor for Python objects is `__new__` and you almost never overwrite it.